# Recommendations for reporting solution that renders html content in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Our users input data using html editors (ckeditor and aspxhtmleidtor) which is saved in the database. Finally a huge report is generated displaying this html. 
I tried xtrareport but they have limited html tag support so report does not look exactly the same as data was inputted by user.

Any recommendation or way around? Please help.

Comment: What format should the report have?

Comment: we want html or rtf or pdf version of report, but it should display in same format as data is inputted through htmleditor..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found no solution...as no reporting Solution provides full HTML tag support, as if they provide... they will end up creating a whole browser engine..
but in my case i found an easy way out....just displayed whole raw html data in html page and with the help of iframe and css i made it appear like a report, then i used ABCpdf to convert from html to pdf to give a nice downloadable pdf version ..

Answer (score 1):

what about `Crystal Report`.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CrystalReportViewer.aspx

Comment: does it display in same format as data is inputted through htmleditor (please also note user also copy paste from ms. word to htmleditor)...so html is complex

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft **ReportViewer** you can add a **TextBox** and right click on **Text** then select Create **Placeholder** and in placeholder you must sure markup type is **HTML**... selcted.

In Value of placeholder you must set:

```
Value='Html Tag'
```